# What is the difference of using 'samba' over 'Folder sharing' on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

On ubuntu, I can go to file browser and 'Folder sharing' and select 'share this folder, I can see this folder on Window machine.

And then I see this guide to setup samba on ubuntu. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html

My question is what can samba provide which does not already provide by the 'folder sharing ' feature?

Answer (score 3):

Folder sharing almost certainly uses samba. The guide you linked to is about setting up a server, allowing you to tweak more settings than just "share this folder". I am pretty sure that they both use samba in the background though.

So, in answer to your question, they are the same thing, set up using different methods.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu’s built-in file-sharing tool uses Samba, which is interoperable with Windows.
Reference: http://www.howtogeek.com/116309/use-ubuntus-public-folder-to-easily-share-files-between-computers/

For more questions about ubuntu related issue you can go to official ubuntu stackexchange site: [www.askubuntu.com](http://www.askubuntu.com)